# Magnific Popup - won't play video

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I'm trying to use the Magnific popup to display a YouTube video. I have an issue that when you click on the link, nothing at all happens. There's no error message and it doesn't revert to back up behaviour (following link to YouTube).

Just using the code from the demo page, with the references updated to suit my own file structure:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/magnific-popup.css"> 

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/magnific.min.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>

  <div class="example gc3">
    <h3>Popup with video or map</h3>
    <p>In this example lightboxes are automatically disabled on small screen size and default behavior of link is triggered.</p>
    <div class="html-code">
      <a class="popup-youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O2aH4XLbto">Open YouTube video</a><br/>
  </div>

  <style type="text/css">
 /*** Simple fade transition*/
 .mfp-fade.mfp-bg {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out; 
 -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out; 
 transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
 }
 .mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-ready {
 opacity: 0.8;
 }
 .mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-removing {
 opacity: 0;
 }
 .mfp-fade.mfp-wrap .mfp-content {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out; 
 -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out; 
 transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
 }
 .mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-ready .mfp-content {
 opacity: 1;
 }
.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-removing .mfp-content {
opacity: 0;
}
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
   disableOn: 700,
   type: 'iframe',
   mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
   removalDelay: 160,
   preloader: false,
   fixedContentPos: false
  });
 });
 </script>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm running it off a server and can't get a result in any of my browsers - Chrome, IE9, Safari, Fiefox.

I looked at the documentation at http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#iframe_type, but I don't actually understand it, so I don't know if that can help me.

Any hints as to what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and then I realized I had downloaded a custom built script, which did not include iframe support. Later I downloaded the full version and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/EF8EF/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
   disableOn: 700,
   type: 'iframe',
   mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
   removalDelay: 160,
   preloader: false,
   fixedContentPos: false
  });
 });
```

I got it working with your code & including the file directly into the body of the Javascript. **It might be the case that you're not calling the magnific-popup code correctly?**

Comment: Thanks for answering, however that's definitely not the case. It's only the iframe functionality I have a problem with - the popup works perfectly if applied to images.

Just editing to say, I'm confounded that the fiddle works, the demo works but using identical code, my test doesn't work. Any chance it could be some setting on the server?

Comment: It could be a number of possibilities - you could have conflicting code, you might not be calling the script properly, you might have some minor errors in your code itself. Is there any way you could show us your live site so we can see where the potential issues are?

Comment: I'm using literally only the code pasted above - the first thing I did when I couldn't make it work in context was strip it right back to bare essentials. The code above doesn't work for me - so whatever the issue is, it is with what you see there.

Comment: This is really strange! Do you have any links we could look at to perhaps dig deeper?